# Aligning 3 divs side by side in a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 3 divs side by side in a navigation bar. I've spent the past 5 hours trying to figure this out and I know it's something super simple that I can't just wrap my head around.

This is where I am at right now.
[image]

If I float the align-right div the tags Join & Support stack ontop of each other.

```
<div id="sticky-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="align-left">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Home</a> <a
                    href="javascript:void(0)">Listings</a>
            </div>
            <div class="align-center">
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="align-right">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Join</a> <a
                    href="javascript:void(0)">Support</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#sticky-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #7889D6;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#sticky-nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    display: block;
}

#sticky-nav input[type=text] {
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sticky-nav button {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    padding-top: 1px; margin-top : 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#sticky-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

#sticky-nav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    display: table-row;
}

.align-left {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: justify;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}

.align-center {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: justify;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}

.align-right {
    width: 33%;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

EDIT: This is the layout I am trying to achieve,
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit? or create a minimal example?

Comment: Updated the post with image of how the layout should appear.

Comment: Try .box{display:flex; justify-content:space-between;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you're using `display: table` to achieve this effect. I **highly** recommend reading up more first before continuing with your work or project. Some layout concepts you have to know are [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) and [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). In your case, we can use the flexbox concept to solve your problem.

`flex` basically is a method that can distribute space between items more easily. In your case, you can get what you're trying to achieve by using `flex-grow` and `flex-basis`. `flex-basis` defines how, initially, long/tall an item inside a flex container should be. `flex-grow` defines how an item inside a flex container can expand (grow) in width/height depending on the remaining space of the container.

In your case, we can simply set the flex container's width (your wrapping div) to 100%. To distribute space evenly between the items, we can set all the items' initial widths to 0. Then, distribute the **remaining** space of the container (which is still 100%) evenly using `flex-grow` to 1 for each flexbox item. However, this will make all the items similar in width. To make the center div wider, you can set the `flex-grow` to 2. This will make it so that the left div, center div, and right div have 25%, 50%, and 25% of the container's **remaining** space in width respectively. I **really** recommend reading further about flex to understand what I mean. After reading about flex in the above link, try visiting [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg) to learn more about `flex-basis` and `flex-grow`.

Here's a working solution using `flex`. Again, I recommend reading more about flex so that you can use flex better.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper * {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.left-align,
.right-align {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.center-align {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.left-align {
  background: #121212;
}

.center-align {
  background: #232323;
}

.right-align {
  background: #454545;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left-align">Some content</div>
  <div class="center-align">Some content</div>
  <div class="right-align">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: After reading up on those articles I was able to get it exactly how I wanted.
Using justify-content: space-between; I was able to position it perfectly.

Comment: @JacksonHogan Glad that I could help ;-) There are always many ways to achieve something. `justify-content: space-between` is one of which. However, `justify-content: space-between` cannot adjust the ratio of each element's width in the container. It adds space such that the items are separated by equal amount of spaces. This can look a little jarring if there's much space in one of the boxes, resulting in more spaces visually (the content space and the space created by flex). Do take a look at the other properties like `space-evenly` too. That being said, there's a downside to my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a simple example for your layout.
You can achieve it using flex box i.e

```
.box{
        display: flex;
        width:100%;
        justify-content:space-between;
      }
```

**Here is the link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-euclid-xmv6h

Hope it answer your question.